# Drupal 7.10 : views filters error

Tags: 7, views

i keep getting the following message on my exposed filters. Any ideas as to what i might have missed out when configuring the filters. I used the cck list (text) widget to compile options in each select list.

ps- i did not select the required option on the views filter options. For each filter i selected the expose filter option, the "is one of" option and the options i want to appear in the filters. I also have the Better formats module selected.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think we need a bit more information. What other options do you have set on the view? What are the settings for this exposed filters? a.s.o.

Comment: For each filter i selected the expose filter option, the "is one of" option and the options i want to appear in the filters. I also have the Better formats module selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common and very difficult to debug problem. It happens when there's an inconsistency between the cache version and the submitted version of a form; whatever the reason.

You're best bet would be to upgrade Views and Ctools (and perhaps BEF too) to the latest dev versions.

Also, one important thing to consider is wether or not you have custom code altering the form.